# Do websites ever delete data about me and my activities?

Tags: privacy, databases, websites

I wanted to know for how long Porn websites retain data about visitors' IP addresses and the specific pages they visit. I wanted to check it for Pornhub, xnxx, and xvideos. However, my country recently blocked all such websites, so I am unable to visit their privacy policy pages.

Can anyone please tell me for how long they retain data (specifically the data I described above) about me and my activity? I tried several times but all the websites are now blocked by my ISP.

By the way, like ISPs, do websites delete such data at all?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is about INFOSEC. It's probably a legal question in theory, while in practice there's probably no way to know what each company does (in spite of the law).

Comment: @reed Yes this isn't really about info-**sec**, but I thought that this is the most reasonable Stack Exchange site to ask. In fact, if someone just copy-pastes their (PornHub, xnxx, xvideos) privacy policy as an answer would be much of a help to me.

Comment: If you are interested about the "theory", that is, when websites are required by law to delete specific data, then Law.SE is probably the appropriate site. However the answer might be complex, depending on the jurisdiction / country / type of website, etc. So your questions might still be closed because they are too broad, opinion-based, etc.

Comment: @reed No, not interested in the legal aspect. And as far as I know, there is no legal requirement imposed upon the websites themselves, rather the requirements are for ISPs. And this question is very specific, as it focusses on 3 porn websites. Moreover, asking "do websites delete data at all" is not broad, as it's logical answer is either yes or no or sometimes, and nothing else.

Comment: "do websites delete data at all?" -- that's entirely up to each site and whatever regulatory context they are in (many jurisdictions require that personal data be deleted after some time)

Comment: @schroeder (1) Yea, It is upto each site. May I know your opinion whether it is feasible for porn sites that have majority of the content in the video form, to store users' watching data for a long time? I mean, even big ISPs can't afford to store all data for long periods, so porn sites can't store it for longer durations either, I guess?

Comment: (2) It is also worth noting that porn sites like PornHub or xnxx receive one of the highest visitors per day. They are the top sites in ranking. So is storing browsing history by a porn site for 2 years a costly deal in your opinion?

Comment: Video sites store data because they want to craft their content and what they promote. They will keep it for a long while to hone their algorithms. ISP keep data for record-keeping.

Comment: @schroeder Yes they want to analyze the data to provide better/desirable content for viewers, so they'll definitely store it for some time, but they don't have enough space to store it for long, is that right? In an official correspondence with PornHub, the spokesperson [pointed out the vast amount of server space they would need to store users' viewing histories—they get 300 million requests a day, and they estimate that storing all of that would require 3,600 terabytes of space.](https://www.vice.com/en/article/539485/your-porn-is-watching-you)

Comment: Does this indicate that they are simply incapable to store it for longer periods?

Comment: That quote is misleading and based on a particular perspective. Do the math: they are saying that they would store 3GB of data for each hit. That's grossly misleading. With a graph database, all they need to do is to store the connections between users and video files with a timestamp.

Comment: @schroeder So unlike ISPs, who have to delete logs because of space limitations, video hosting sites do not face space problems and do not necessarily need to delete anything to "free up space"?

Comment: If they use an efficient data storage system, they can keep the data far longer. Any company, porn site or ISP, will keep the data for as long as its value to them is greater than the costs of keeping it. It's really basic logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write a short answer anyway, even though I believe this question is not relevant in this community, and it's probably going to be closed soon (I see 2 close votes already).

Here are some relevant parts from PorhHub's privacy policy:

> #### Your Rights Related to Your Personal Information
>
> You may exercise your right to access and deletion [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Please note that unless you have created an account with us, we may
> not have sufficient information to identify you and therefore may not
> be in a position to respond to your request. Additionally, in some
> cases in order to adequately verify your identity or your
> authorization to make the request, we may require you to provide
> additional information.
>
> #### Retention of Personal Information
>
> We will only retain your personal information for as long as your
> account is active, or **for as long as necessary to fulfil the purposes
> we collected it for**, including for the purposes of satisfying any
> legal, accounting, or reporting requirements.
>
> To determine the appropriate retention period for personal data, we
> consider a number of factors, including what personal data we are
> processing, the risk of harm from any unauthorised disclosure, why we
> are processing your personal data and whether we can achieve this
> outcome by another means without having to process it.
>
> Where we no longer need to process your personal information for the
> purposes set out in this Privacy Policy, we will delete your personal
> information from our systems.
>
> Where permissible, we will also delete your personal information upon
> your request as explained above in the section “Your Rights Related to
> Your Personal Information”.

So there's no way to know, unless you contact them and ask for more details (and I'm not sure they will give you all the details you want, although according to the GDPR you should have the right to ask them and they might be required to give an answer). In any case, supposing they told you they delete all traffic logs after 6 months, are you going to believe them? Is there a way to know if they are lying, or if their policies are actually enforced? No (unless there's an investigation or something).

Xvideos' privacy policy is similar, they provide no details other than saying that they retain your personal information for as long as necessary. How long should a website keep the traffic logs for security purposes? I have no idea. It would be an interesting question to ask, but as always I have no idea whether it would be considered opinion-based here.

Comment: This answer explains that there is no correct answer unless and until someone investigates about their privacy policies directly with them. This satisfies my curiosity. Thanks for writing this!

Comment: *"...supposing they told you they delete all traffic logs after 6 months, are you going to believe them?"*  ---  But if they say so, there is a high chance that they won't be lying because porn sites are full of videos and porn sites receive one of the highest visitors per day. Storing data for longer seems disastrous for their own business. What do you think on this?

Comment: @AndrewRozario, they store and stream a gazillion HD videos every day, I doubt some compressed plaintext logs are going to be a problem for them, however large. Then it depends on the purpose of those logs, but there is really no way to find out if they are telling the truth about their internal processes. I doubt they keep all the data for more than a few months though. After that, they'll probably just keep anonymized statistics (forever). IPs logged as part of some "security alert" might be kept for longer though, etc.

Comment: Why do you *"doubt they keep all the data for more than a few months"*?

Comment: @AndrewRozario, because it's probably useless in its raw, original form, so I suppose they would transform it into some kind of statistical data, or compress it to keep only some meaningful data (unique IPs, alerts, etc.). But this is just my opinion, just a guess. In Europe, the GDPR (a privacy law) says you need to delete personal data (including IPs) once it's not useful anymore (but PornHub is an American Company).

Comment: Xvideos and Xnxx are European and were founded in Paris by a French owner. I guess they are bound by GDPR?

Comment: @AndrewRozario yes, it looks like they need to comply with the GDPR. However the GDPR doesn't mention any fixed periods of time or time limits for keeping personal data, so it's open to interpretation. I'm not sure how long a full log can be considered useful. "A few months" (say 6 to 12 months) is just a guess of mine. "How long should I keep logs for security purposes" might be a interesting related question that could be asked (but I'm not sure if it would be appropriate here)